# Input/output error with fuse filesystem on linux?

Tags: linux, fuse, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I'm trying to mount my filesystem to a empty directory. The directory is `/home/test`. I have the following functions already written:

- access
- getattr
- readdir
- statfs
- mkdir
- rmdir
- create
- write
- read

I use the command `./fusetest /home/test -d` to mount my filesystem. When I try to `ls` under the directory of `/home/test`, I get the error information:

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Input/output error"
```

Like the following image shows :

[image]

And the debug information is here:
[image]

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: You should probably show the code for some of the functions. `open` and `read` seem like top candidates. Also, the value of `$?` may be helpful to pull the error code from the shell.

Comment: I am sorry that I have not understanded you meanings. Because I implemented a DFS by c++. The code is too much . And how to use the value of  $? Thankyou very much!

Comment: Well, you need to have to provide something for Stack Overflow to work with. Without the relevant code someone needs a orbuculum to hazard a guess. Do you have a GitHub with the source? `echo $?` prints the last error. In your case, it may give you a toehold for the problem, or it may be totally irrelevant.

Comment: oh,I know your meanings. The code haven't opened on github so far.

Comment: For me, I had a bad fuse mount.  I did a umount -a bad_directory and the directory behaved normally again.

Answer (score 0):

Your debug information doesn't show the os.ModeDir info. I'm guessing you didn't do a binary conversion between your unit type code and the required format. It goes something like this for Golang (since your question doesn't specify the language or the library you're using):

```
attr.Mode = os.ModeDir | uint32(0644)
```